# how to Concatenate two Columns in Combobox C# From Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

hi i am binding a combobox from source code... now i want to concatenate it with an other database column with same table.... my source code is.... :

```
<div class="dnnFormItem">
<dnn:Label  ResourceKey="LBLEmpId" Text="Name:" runat="server" id="dlbEmpId" ControlName="ddlEmpId"  />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmpId" DataTextField="FName" DataValueField="Id" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Here my "DataTextField="FName" but i want to display First name + Last name "DataTextField="FName + LName"... and my C# code is:

```
`public void ddlEmpIdbind()
 {
  this.ddlEmpId.DataSource = new DocEmpProfile.DocEmpProfileController().GetAll(this.PortalId);
  this.ddlEmpId.DataBind();
  ListItem li = new ListItem();
  li.Text = "Select Employee";
  li.Value = "-1";
  li.Selected = true;
  this.ddlEmpId.Items.Insert(0, li);
  } `
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a read-only property on your domain object, something like:

```
public string FullName {
    get {
        return string.format("{0} {1}", this.FName, this.LName);
    }
}
```

and bind that to your combobox DataTextField property. Consider doing this in a partial class.